# Square integrability of martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales

So we had the following example in class:

Assume $(\Omega, ℱ,(ℱ_{t}),ℙ)$ a filtered probability space and $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ a random variable such that 
$$ 
\mathbb{E}[|X|^{2}] < \infty \quad .
$$

Then the stochastic process $(M)_{t\geq 0}$ defined by

$$
M_t := \mathbb{E}[X|ℱ_{t}] 
$$

for all $t \geq 0$ is a $ℱ_{t}$ - martingale.

So I was wondering whether in this case the martingale $(M)_t$ is square-integrable, i. e.

$$
\mathbb{E}[|M_t|^{2}] < \infty 
$$

for all $t \geq 0$, because of the square integrability of the random variable $X$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is. This follows from Jensen's inequality (for conditional expectations).

Comment: Many thanks for ur super quick reply.